# SLDS and inputField checkbox

Tags: visualforce, slds

So, the SLDS says that a checkbox must be done like this:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-checkbox" for="checkboxSample1">
    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkboxSample1" />
    <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
    <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox Label</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

that is all well and good and it works.

**BUT** how the heck do you do it with an apex:inputField???

This produces the correct looking UI but you cannot check or uncheck the box

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-checkbox" for="provider_contacted">

        <apex:inPutField id="provider_contacted" value="{!loc.Provider_Contacted__c}"/>
        <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Provider Contacted</span>

    </label>

</div>
```

and if you attempt to do this:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="received">
        Received
    </label>

    <apex:inPutField id="received" value="{!loc.Received__c}"
                     styleClass="slds-checkbox slds-input slds-form-element__control"/>

</div>
```

It renders as follows (loosing SLDS styling)

[image]

So my question:

**Q:** How do you style an `<apex:inputCheckbox>` like a SLDS checkbox

**Current Solution**

Remove the `for=` from the label **duh**

<strike>Doing it this way, but is there a way that does not require JS for every element?</strike>

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-checkbox" for="provider_contacted">

        <apex:inPutField id="provider_contacted" value="{!loc.Provider_Contacted__c}"/>
        <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" onclick="toggleCheckbox($('[id$=provider_contacted]'));"></span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Provider Contacted</span>
    </label>

</div>

    <script>
        function toggleCheckbox(e){
            $(e).prop("checked", !(e).prop("checked"));
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes SLDS is  CSS framework. for manipulating the element and binding value, we require js.  Salesforce should need to take a step and make SLDS compatible with VF standard component. So we can use VF standard component with SLDS styles

Comment: @Ratan - NO JS is required to check / uncheck the checkbox if using a plain html input instead of an <apex:inputfield> - so curious as to why an input element created using an apex:inputChecbox breaks it vs a regular html input element

Comment: Yes correct @Eric

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Eric Edit**

The answer provided by Ashwani is the correct way to do it. However, **the actual reason for my issue** in the question was **that I had left the `for=` in the label**. If you take this answer and add a `for=xxx` to the label you will notice what I saw in my original question.

This answer gave the proof of concept that it worked as I thought it should. I would have never taken another look at it otherwise so thank you....

**End Edit**

I did it this way and worked perfectly. <strike>You need to give `styleclass="slds-input"` attribute for `inputField`/`inputCheckbox`</strike>(*Eric note:* This is best practice but striking just to highlight that it was not the reason for what I saw).

```
     <div class="slds-form-element__row">
       <div class="slds-form-element">
          <label class="slds-checkbox">
                <apex:inputcheckbox id="isinstance" styleclass="slds-input" value="{!isSameInstance}" />
                   <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                   <span class="slds-form-element__label">Are you Tier 3?</span>
          </label>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok, so your answer got me looking at other things. Thanks for the kick in the pants... What the issue ended up being was I left the dang `for=` in the label. no slds-input was needed on the input field. If you do not mind me adding the actual cause of the issue to your answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Please go ahead. @Eric

Comment: Thanks, please feel free to edit my edits. Tried to get point across that your answer was best practice yet highlight the actual reason for what I saw...Thank you again for taking the time to provide the answer. Remove a bunch of onclick JS that was not needed lol

Comment: @Eric. Answer looks perfect. Auto-correct feature always mesh my name :)

Comment: I usually just avoided the slds-checkbox, but I had a development where it was a requirement and this answer is spot on. Thanks!